# Dual monitor: losing focus on terminal app when using cmd+tab

Tags: catalina, application-switcher, dual-screen

Webdeveloper here. This is the situation:

I have two sceens,

- on screen one there is a terminal window running my webserver
- on screen two there is a terminal window where I type my commands and there is a text editor (atom).

I want to cmd+tab between the terminal and editor on screen two. But when I do, and I cmd+tab from the editor to the terminal, the focus is suddenly on the terminal on screen one (and thereby accidentally typing all kind of stuff in the server output)

So, is there a way to make a window of an app the 'main' window? (the terminal on screen two in this case) So that when you cmd+tab to the application the focus will be on this 'main' window?

In `System Preferences > Displays > Arrangement`, I already moved the white taskbar to screen two. This does not solve the problem

I cant recall I had this problem before. Is this new functionality in Catalina?

Answer (score 1):

You can press <kbd>CMD</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> to switch between windows of the same application.

This doesn't fix the root cause of the focus issue, but does allow you to select the correct Terminal window via the keyboard.

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of that shortcut, but like you said: will unfortunately not solve the original problem